# How to calculate the number of distinct energy levels below a certain energy level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

The energy levels of a infinite square well is given by :
$$\epsilon=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}r^2$$
The number of energy levels below a certain energy level for large quantum numbers (for large r), $\epsilon$ is given,
$$\phi(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{8}(\frac{4\pi r^3}{3})=\frac{\pi}{6}\Big(\frac{8ml^2\epsilon}{h^2}\Big)^\frac{3}{2}.$$
How to derive this expression for $\phi(\epsilon)$ ?
I tried to do it as follows :
$$\epsilon=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}r^2$$
$$ d\epsilon= \frac{h^2}{8ml^2}(2rdr).$$
Then I thought to divide the $d\epsilon$ by the lowest value of energy, to calculate $d\ n$ . But found that the spacing between the energy levels are not the same. So, I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Write $r=(8m\ell^2 \epsilon/\hbar^2)^{1/2}$ and take the third power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are already thinking in the $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ space.
The number of distinct energy states is the "volume" in this space.
You have the energy
$$\epsilon=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)=\frac{h^2}{8ml^2}r^2$$
or solved for $r$
$$r=\left(\frac{8ml^2\epsilon}{h^2}\right)^{1/2}. \tag{1}$$

The three quantum numbers $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ are all positive.
Therefore you need to calculate not the volume of the whole sphere,
but only the volume of its first [octant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)).

[image]
<sub>(image from [Physical Applications of Surface Integrals](https://www.math24.net/physical-applications-surface-integrals-page-2/),
slightly modified by me)</sub>

You find the volume of the octant be
$$\phi(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\right)
=\frac{\pi}{6}r^3.$$
Now insert the radius $r$ from (1) and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much @Thomas Fritsch

Comment: But two distinct sets of (n_x, n_y, n_z) can give same energy. Has it been considered in the derivation @Thomas Fritsch

Comment: @bubucodex Yes, this is already already considered in the derivation.
If you have two different $(n_x, n_y, n_z)$ (like for example $(1,3,4)$ and $(4,3,1)$) giving the same $r$,
then these as just two different places within the sphere at the same radius $r$.

Comment: Within which sphere ? Is it within a sphere of radius greater than given by (1,3,4) or (4,3,1) ? That means within such a sphere these two points are considered separately ? This means these two points are not giving two distinct energy levels and still both of them contribute to the volume. So, I am confused as you have mentioned that number of distinct energy levels contribute to the volume.

Comment: @bubucodex Yes, they are considered as separate points,
albeit at the same distance ($r=\sqrt{26}$) from the origin,
and thus with the same energy.

Comment: So, probably it should be distinct energy "states", not "levels" . @Thomas Fritsch

Comment: @bubucodex Ah yes, I fixed the wording in my answer.

Comment: By the way, thank you so much @Thomas Fritsch